# Is there a way for me to force an HTML <ul> to be a fixed size in order to make an SPA?

Tags: html, css, single-page-application

I want to make an SPA for a project. The idea is that people can connect to the site via a PIN or something. On their phones, they can ask questions along with their names. All of the questions appear as a vertical unordered list in a sidebar on the left, the selected question appears big in the center and all answered questions move to a similar list in a sidebar on the right.

Currently, the list works fine, but as soon as there are more than four questions, the list becomes taller than the page itself and I think that's hideous. I want to have it scrollable, but at a limited height.

**What I've tried:**

- I've tried setting the `height` and `max-height` properties to 100vh, and setting `overflow-y` to scroll, but didn't actually allow me to scroll the list.

In the stylesheet:

```
li {
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  list-style-type: none;

  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

And in my HTML:

```
 <body>
    <script src="backend.js"></script>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="vragenLijst">
        <ul style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px" id="lijst">
          <li>
            <div>
              <p class="vrager">Persoon 1</p>
              <br>
              <p class="vraagt">vraagt:</p>
              <br>
              <p class="vraagEl">Dit is mijn vraag.</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div>
              <p class="vrager">Persoon nummer twee</p>
              <br>
              <p class="vraagt">vraagt:</p>
              <br>
              <p class="vraagEl">Hier komt mijn vraag dan, zeer origineel.</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div>
              <p class="vrager">Persoon nummer 3</p>
              <br>
              <p class="vraagt">wilt weten:</p>
              <br>
              <p class="vraagEl">En wederom wat opvultekst hier.</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div>
              <p class="vrager">Vierde persoon</p>
              <br>
              <p class="vraagt">wilt weten:</p>
              <br>
              <p class="vraagEl">Zo he, een vierde vraag? Allemachtig...</p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="vergroot">
        <p id="groteVrager">Naam</p>
        <p id="groteVraagt">vraagt:</p>
        <p id="groteVraag">vraag</p>
        <input type="button" value="Volgende vraag" class="button" onclick="nieuweVraag()">

        <input type="button" value="JA" class="button" onclick="nieuweVraag(0)">
        <input type="button" value="NEE" class="button" onclick="nieuweVraag(1)">
        <input type="button" value="NIET RELEVANT" class="button" nieuweVraag(2)="antwoord(2)">


      </div>
      <div class="sidebar">
        <ul id="beantwoordeVragen">

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      Idee en code door Simeon Duwel, gelicenciëerd onder MIT ca. 2019
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Do you want the <li> or <ul> to have the fixed height? Your css as posted sets the unordered list item with the max height, but your question subject suggests you want the overarching <ul> to be fixed in height.

Comment: UL will grow to accommodate the size of its contents. "fixed height" and "scrollable" are mutually exclusive requirements.

Comment: @AnsonWHan So I moved the `overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;` stuff to ul in css, but it still has the same problem

Comment: @WalrusGumboot I believe that should work, unless you have other conflicting CSS

Answer (score 0):

Setting `overflow-y:auto` and `height: <desired-height>` to the **ul** should work.

For example, below I have a ul with a height of 50 vh. For demonstration purposes I have a yellow-colored div with 100vh. As you can see, the ul height is fixed as half of the div, and any overflow scrolls.

```css
ul {
  height: 50vh;
  background-color:white;
  overflow-y:auto;
}

li {
  height: 10vh;
}

body,ul {
   margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:100vh;background-color:yellow">
  <ul>
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <li>Test 2</li>
    <li>Test 3</li>
    <li>Test 4</li>
    <li>Test 5</li>
    <li>Test 6</li>
    <li>Test 7</li>
    <li>Test 8</li>
    <li>Test 9</li>
    <li>Test 10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```